# How to allocate a Win32 Structure with an Dynamic Array inside?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

Delphi 11 WinNt(10) Struggling with an Range Exception.

I can "Solve" then Problem by disabling the Range Check {$R-} but does anyone know the correct new way?

This Structure should be the definition. I got it from a 3. Party and microsoft Win32 online Help doesnt have a definition for me. I Guess that the array[0..0] is not correct for a Dynamic length result ...

```
SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_DISTRIBUTION = record
  ProcessorCount: ULONG;
  Offsets: array[0..0] of ULONG; // this would be the dynamic Part
end;
```

If i want to use my Structure, i can only use the first Offset[0] entry before the Range Error. As Expected... But how to allocate that Structure correct?

```
function QueryProcessorPerformance(out ABuffer: PSystemProcessorPerformanceDistribution): boolean;
var
  status: NTSTATUS;
  buffer: Pointer absolute aBuffer; // Mapping my Pointer from aBuffer to local Pointer buffer
  bufferSize: ULong;
begin
  buffer  := nil;
  bufferSize:=0;
  status:=NtQuerySystemInformation(ProcessorPerformanceDistribution{Somenumber},buffer,bufferSize,@bufferSize);
  if (ULong(status) = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) then // Excepted
  begin
    AallocMem(buffer,bufferSize);
    status:=NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceDistribution,buffer,bufferSize,@bufferSize);
    // from here on aBuffer has a Valid Count Value.
    if status = s_ok then
    begin
      // Acces to 
      aBuffer^.Offsets[0] is ok. aBuffer^.Offsets[1] Throws Range Check
    end;
  end;
  Result:=status=S_OK;
end;
```

Comment: You just need to disable range checking when you access the elements. You could add a method to the record that accessed the elements by index, but disable range checking in just that method. That's a bit odd though. I'd just wrap it a bit more and have the function return `TArray<ULONG>` and hide the gnarly variable length array from the caller completely. Then you can handle the deallocation too so that the caller doesn't need to. A couple of other comments. The use of absolute seems odd. Not sure why you'd need that. Also, `S_OK` is for `HRESULT`. You need `STATUS_SUCCESS`.

Comment: "*I Guess that the array[0..0] is not correct for a Dynamic length result*" - [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043)

Comment: Another way to avoid a Range Check error would be to use pointer arithmetic to access the elements, eg: `(@(aBuffer.Offsets[0]) + index)^` or `var P: PULONG; P := aBuffer.Offsets; Inc(P, index); use P^`

Answer (score 0):

Currently for Delphi 11 the answer is:

- Disable the RangeCheck as per David Heffernan´s suggestion

or be (in my mind) brave and

- go the Pointer Arithmetik Route from Remy Lebeau´s solution.

Both Work, I prefer the Range Check Version.

Thank you both once again.